# Is there any way to transport a data to MongoDB from MariaDB directly?

Tags: mongodb, mariadb

Now I store a data in MariaDB and I can't change my Database.

but I want to transport this data to mongoDB as soon as possible.

Is there any way to transport a data to MongoDB from MariaDB directly?

Thank you.

Comment: MariaDB is a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#RDBMS) whereas MongoDB is a [document-oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) (also known as NoSQL). These are quite different concepts. You should evaluate your use case carefully, which database is best for you.

Comment: related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111826/mongodb-to-mysql-replication-automatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't directly replicate the data from MariaDB to MongoDB. You need to use a middleware between application and MariaDB or service between MariaDB and MongoDB for that.

**Update:**

*The solution is suggested by [Georg Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6930501/georg-richter)*

If you don't need replication, but just need to transfer (copy) data from the MariaDB into MongoDB, then you can use the [CONNECT storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect/).
It will allow to you have a direct [connection from MariaDB to MongoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-mongo-table-type/). Then you can use the SQL queries (e.g. `INSERT ... SELECT`) for the data transfer.

Comment: You can directly transfer data by using the connect engine. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-mongo-table-type

Comment: @GeorgRichter can you show an example (or manual) how to implement the data replication from MariaDB into MongoDB (Master-Slave)? Because I see only that it give the possibility of access to MongoDB via MariaDB, but not replicate data from MariaDB to MongoDB.

Comment: The question didn't ask for replication but for transferring data from a MariaDB database/table to MongoDB which can be done via SQL (and also automated by using triggers). For replication this will of course not work, a replication solution would be to use tungsten-replicator.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Okay, maybe I misinterpreted `...I want to transport this data to MongoDB as soon as possible...` as a wish to have a data replication from MariaDB to MongoDB. Thanks for pointing out it. I updated my answer.